# How does the Beta Israelite community interpret Wayikra/Leviticus 16 in regards to the scapegoat, "Azazel"?

Tags: minhag, commentaries, parshat-acharei-mot, ethiopian-beta-israel, azazel

To my understanding, the [Beta Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel) community accepts [HaSepher Chanoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch) within their [canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymanot).  That being said within HaSepher Chanoch, Azazel is described as a fallen angel ([Enoch Literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel#Enochic_literature)) which is in contrast to how Azazel is interpreted as ["The word Azazel indicates that the cliff the goat is pushed from should be rough and hard"](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.67b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). I also came across [Legends of the Jews](https://www.sefaria.org/Legends_of_the_Jews.1.4.9?ven=The_Legends_of_the_Jews_by_Louis_Ginzberg_%5B1909%5D&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), viewing Azazel as a fallen angel imprisoned on sharp-pointed stones in the desert.  How does the Beta Israelite community interpret Wayikra 16 in regards to the scapegoat, "Azazel"?  Are there literature, commentary, and/or articles that highlight how the community interprets who or what Azazel is in regards to Wayikra/Leviticus 16?  Todah Rabbah

Comment: Very relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31273/who-is-azazel-its-the-guy-that-got-one-of-the-two-goats-on-a-certain-day-what

Comment: @Harel13 Peace and Love.  I really appreciate your answer (and for even asking) beloved.  If you make your comment into an answer, I will award you the bounty.......I guess the better question would be then how did they interpret before touching base in Israel I suppose.....

Comment: @Harel13 Do you know of any other ancient sects that did hold Chanoch in high esteem or holy?

Comment: @Harel13 I saw that and as you made mentioned, being spoken about in other midrashim.  Seeing and coming across elements within this particular question (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/122078/22051) makes me wonder why this particular school of thought didn't become more dominant or even rival Azazel meaning more than just a physical location or just "scapegoat".